# Changing the background colour of a bchart

Tags: backgrounds, bchart

How can I change the background colour of a `bchart`?
In this case it appears a blue nuance (I guess it's the standard).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,roman]{article}
\usepackage{bchart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{bchart}[step=100,max=200]
\bcbar[text=Bule,value=19419]{194.19}
\bcbar[text=Inserție,value=19513]{195.13}
\bcbar[text=Shell,value=19513]{195.13}
\bcbar[text=Interclasare,value=19517]{195.17}
\bcbar[text=Rapidă,value=19525]{195.25}
\bcbar[text=Selecție,value=19537]{195.37}
\end{bchart}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `color` option for `\bcbar` as in the following example. But you should consider using a different approach for data visualization for better distinction between the entries.

[image: diagram]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,roman]{article}
\usepackage{bchart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{bchart}[step=100,max=200]
\bcbar[text=Bule,value=19419,color=green]{194.19}
\bcbar[text=Inserție,value=19513,color=blue]{195.13}
\bcbar[text=Shell,value=19513,color=yellow]{195.13}
\bcbar[text=Interclasare,value=19517,color=red]{195.17}
\bcbar[text=Rapidă,value=19525,color=pink]{195.25}
\bcbar[text=Selecție,value=19537,color=orange]{195.37}
\end{bchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No criticism to the answer, that is perfect  (+1), but I cannot  resist a off-topic comment  about the result:  The graph is now a rainbow tablecloth as unclear as before. The problem in this graph (of course, IMO, the OP has the right of  think differently)  is not the color but the x-scale. Hiding the decimals values does not help either .  Instead, some  like`\begin{bchart}[step=1,min=193,max=196] 
\bcbar[text=Bule]{194.19} ...` seems to me  clearer and more elegant.